# Ggplot2 doesn't scale Y axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm having a problem regarding scaling Y axis on the ggplot2. I have a dataset (dane_dlugie) consisted of dates (Data) and river flow observations at three different spots (Osielec, Jordanów and Skawica Dolna). My goal is to plot flows from Osielec regarding the proper date.

My plot code looks like this:

```
ggplot(dane_dlugie, aes(x=Data, y=Osielec, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+labs(x="Data", y="Flow") +
  ggtitle("Osielec")+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d-%m")
```

On the Y axis, I would like to have flow scale with the break of 1 m3/s. I've tried using the `'scale_y_discrete'` however without any success.

Could anyone help me with that?

Please find below the reproducible example.

```
dane_dlugie <- structure(list(Data = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), mon = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
    110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
    110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), wday = c(6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L), yday = c(120L, 120L, 120L, 
    120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
    120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
    120L, 121L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Osielec = c("1.281", 
"1.294", "1.294", "1.281", "1.268", "1.281", "1.294", "1.333", 
"1.32", "1.32", "1.333", "1.307", "1.333", "1.346", "1.346", 
"1.359", "1.32", "1.32", "1.294", "1.5328", "2.0296", "2.1952", 
"2.7541", "4.1775", "4.5983"), Jordanów = structure(c(124L, 124L, 
118L, 115L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 115L, 103L, 111L, 127L, 120L, 122L, 
120L, 116L, 125L, 122L, 111L, 122L, 206L, 258L, 236L, 234L, 266L, 
281L), .Label = c("", "0,1672", "0,1696", "0,172", "0,1744", 
"0,1768", "0,1792", "0,1816", "0,184", "0,1864", "0,1888", "0,1912", 
"0,1936", "0,196", "0,1984", "0,2008", "0,2032", "0,2056", "0,208", 
"0,2104", "0,2128", "0,2152", "0,2176", "0,22", "0,2224", "0,2248", 
"0,2272", "0,2296", "0,232", "0,2344", "0,2368", "0,2392", "0,2416", 
"0,244", "0,2464", "0,2488", "0,2512", "0,2536", "0,256", "0,2584", 
"0,2608", "0,2632", "0,2656", "0,268", "0,2704", "0,2728", "0,2752", 
"0,2776", "0,28", "0,2824", "0,2848", "0,2872", "0,2896", "0,2944", 
"0,2968", "0,2992", "0,3016", "0,304", "0,3064", "0,3088", "0,3112", 
"0,3136", "0,316", "0,3184", "0,3208", "0,3232", "0,3256", "0,3264", 
"0,328", "0,3304", "0,3328", "0,333", "0,3352", "0,3354", "0,3362", 
"0,3376", "0,34", "0,3424", "0,3448", "0,3472", "0,3496", "0,3497", 
"0,352", "0,3544", "0,3568", "0,3588", "0,3592", "0,3616", "0,3623", 
"0,364", "0,3664", "0,3688", "0,3712", "0,3736", "0,376", "0,3784", 
"0,3808", "0,3832", "0,3856", "0,388", "0,3904", "0,3928", "0,394", 
"0,3952", "0,3976", "0,4", "0,4042", "0,4076", "0,4084", "0,4126", 
"0,4144", "0,4168", "0,4178", "0,421", "0,4212", "0,4246", "0,4252", 
"0,428", "0,4294", "0,4314", "0,4336", "0,4348", "0,4378", "0,4382", 
"0,4416", "0,442", "0,445", "0,4462", "0,4484", "0,4504", "0,4518", 
"0,4546", "0,4552", "0,4588", "0,463", "0,4672", "0,4714", "0,4756", 
"0,4798", "0,484", "0,4882", "0,4924", "0,4966", "0,5008", "0,505", 
"0,5092", "0,5134", "0,5176", "0,5218", "0,526", "0,5302", "0,5344", 
"0,5386", "0,5428", "0,547", "0,5512", "0,5554", "0,5596", "0,5638", 
"0,568", "0,5722", "0,5764", "0,5806", "0,5848", "0,589", "0,5932", 
"0,5974", "0,6016", "0,6058", "0,61", "0,6116", "0,6142", "0,6184", 
"0,6226", "0,6268", "0,631", "0,6352", "0,6394", "0,6436", "0,6478", 
"0,652", "0,6562", "0,6604", "0,6646", "0,6688", "0,673", "0,6772", 
"0,6814", "0,6856", "0,6898", "0,694", "0,6982", "0,7024", "0,7066", 
"0,7108", "0,715", "0,7192", "0,7234", "0,7276", "0,7318", "0,736", 
"0,7402", "0,7444", "0,7486", "0,7528", "0,7556", "0,757", "0,7584", 
"0,7612", "0,7654", "0,7696", "0,7738", "0,778", "0,7822", "0,7864", 
"0,7906", "0,7948", "0,799", "0,8032", "0,8074", "0,8116", "0,8158", 
"0,82", "0,8258", "0,8316", "0,8374", "0,8432", "0,849", "0,8548", 
"0,8606", "0,8664", "0,8722", "0,878", "0,8804", "0,8838", "0,8856", 
"0,8896", "0,8954", "0,9012", "0,907", "0,9128", "0,9186", "0,9244", 
"0,9302", "0,936", "0,9418", "0,9476", "0,9534", "0,9592", "0,965", 
"0,9708", "0,9766", "0,9824", "0,9882", "0,9916", "0,994", "0,9998", 
"1,0052", "1,0056", "1,0064", "1,0114", "1,0172", "1,023", "1,0288", 
"1,0346", "1,0364", "1,0404", "1,0462", "1,052", "1,0578", "1,0636", 
"1,0694", "1,0752", "1,081", "1,0868", "1,0926", "1,0984", "1,1042", 
"1,11", "1,1158", "1,1196", "1,1216", "1,1248", "1,1274", "1,1332", 
"1,139", "1,1448", "1,1506", "1,156", "1,1564", "1,1622", "1,1664", 
"1,168", "1,1738", "1,1796", "1,1854", "1,1912", "1,197", "1,2028", 
"1,2086", "1,2144", "1,2184", "1,2202", "1,2236", "1,226", "1,2288", 
"1,2318", "1,234", "1,2376", "1,2492", "1,2496", "1,2548", "1,255", 
"1,26", "1,2608", "1,2666", "1,2724", "1,2754", "1,2782", "1,284", 
"1,2898", "1,2908", "1,2956", "1,2985", "1,3014", "1,3072", "1,313", 
"1,3139", "1,3188", "1,3246", "1,3293", "1,3304", "1,3362", "1,337", 
"1,3415", "1,342", "1,3478", "1,3536", "1,3594", "1,3652", "1,3678", 
"1,371", "1,3755", "1,3768", "1,3826", "1,3884", "1,3942", "1,4", 
"1,408", "1,414", "1,416", "1,4217", "1,424", "1,432", "1,4371", 
"1,44", "1,4448", "1,448", "1,4525", "1,4602", "1,464", "1,4679", 
"1,472", "1,4756", "1,48", "1,4833", "1,488", "1,491", "1,496", 
"1,4987", "1,5064", "1,512", "1,5141", "1,52", "1,528", "1,536", 
"1,5372", "1,544", "1,5449", "1,552", "1,5526", "1,56", "1,5603", 
"1,568", "1,5757", "1,576", "1,5834", "1,584", "1,5911", "1,592", 
"1,6065", "1,608", "1,616", "1,6219", "1,624", "1,632", "1,64", 
"1,648", "1,6527", "1,664", "1,672", "1,68", "1,6835", "1,688", 
"1,6912", "1,696", "1,6989", "1,704", "1,7066", "1,712", "1,7143", 
"1,7297", "1,736", "1,744", "1,7451", "1,752", "1,7528", "1,76", 
"1,768", "1,776", "1,7836", "1,784", "1,792", "1,799", "1,8", 
"1,8067", "1,816", "1,8221", "1,824", "1,8298", "1,832", "1,8375", 
"1,84", "1,8452", "1,848", "1,8529", "1,856", "1,864", "1,872", 
"1,876", "1,888", "1,8914", "1,896", "1,8991", "1,904", "1,9068", 
"1,912", "1,92", "1,9222", "1,928", "1,936", "1,9376", "1,944", 
"1,9453", "1,952", "1,953", "1,96", "1,968", "1,9684", "1,976", 
"1,984", "1,9915", "1,992", "10,0136", "10,014", "10,035", "10,098", 
"10,14", "10,203", "10,371", "10,434", "10,455", "10,518", "10,539", 
"10,56", "10,833", "10,854", "10,875", "10,938", "10,959", "11,064", 
"11,106", "11,169", "11,184", "11,211", "11,232", "11,274", "11,337", 
"11,358", "11,444", "11,576", "11,664", "11,686", "11,862", "11,884", 
"12,104", "12,214", "12,236", "12,368", "12,434", "12,456", "12,72", 
"12,786", "12,918", "12,94", "13,028", "13,05", "13,072", "13,094", 
"13,182", "13,27", "13,314", "13,325", "13,424", "13,446", "13,578", 
"13,715", "13,991", "14,014", "14,037", "14,083", "14,152", "14,29", 
"14,451", "14,497", "14,635", "14,727", "14,819", "14,957", "15,003", 
"15,164", "15,21", "15,225", "15,375", "15,417", "15,44", "15,601", 
"15,67", "15,805", "15,808", "16,125", "16,15", "16,183", "16,291", 
"16,35", "16,399", "16,45", "16,65", "16,725", "16,925", "17,15", 
"17,225", "17,475", "17,775", "17,938", "18,1", "18,2", "18,325", 
"18,35", "18,562", "18,778", "18,886", "19,021", "19,048", "19,102", 
"19,237", "19,453", "19,588", "19,696", "19,885", "19,912", "2", 
"2,0069", "2,008", "2,0146", "2,016", "2,024", "2,032", "2,04", 
"2,0494", "2,056", "2,064", "2,0688", "2,072", "2,08", "2,088", 
"2,0882", "2,096", "2,104", "2,1076", "2,112", "2,12", "2,127", 
"2,128", "2,136", "2,1367", "2,144", "2,152", "2,16", "2,1658", 
"2,168", "2,176", "2,184", "2,1852", "2,192", "2,2", "2,21", 
"2,2143", "2,22", "2,224", "2,23", "2,2337", "2,24", "2,2434", 
"2,25", "2,2531", "2,26", "2,27", "2,2725", "2,28", "2,29", "2,3", 
"2,3016", "2,31", "2,3113", "2,32", "2,321", "2,33", "2,3404", 
"2,35", "2,3598", "2,36", "2,3695", "2,37", "2,3889", "2,39", 
"2,3986", "2,4", "2,41", "2,418", "2,4277", "2,43", "2,4374", 
"2,44", "2,4471", "2,45", "2,4568", "2,46", "2,47", "2,4762", 
"2,48", "2,4859", "2,49", "2,5053", "2,51", "2,515", "2,52", 
"2,5247", "2,54", "2,5441", "2,55", "2,56", "2,5635", "2,58", 
"2,5829", "2,59", "2,5926", "2,6", "2,61", "2,62", "2,63", "2,64", 
"2,6411", "2,65", "2,6508", "2,66", "2,67", "2,6799", "2,68", 
"2,69", "2,6993", "2,7", "2,71", "2,7187", "2,72", "2,7284", 
"2,73", "2,7381", "2,7478", "2,75", "2,7575", "2,76", "2,7672", 
"2,78", "2,7866", "2,79", "2,7963", "2,8", "2,81", "2,82", "2,8254", 
"2,83", "2,8351", "2,84", "2,8448", "2,85", "2,8545", "2,86", 
"2,8642", "2,87", "2,8739", "2,88", "2,89", "2,8933", "2,9", 
"2,91", "2,9127", "2,92", "2,9224", "2,93", "2,94", "2,9418", 
"2,95", "2,9515", "2,96", "2,97", "2,98", "2,9806", "2,99", "2,9903", 
"20,101", "20,155", "20,182", "20,217", "20,506", "20,695", "21,43", 
"21,52", "21,713", "21,94", "22,03", "22,09", "22,27", "22,63", 
"22,78", "23,015", "23,046", "23,14", "23,59", "23,65", "23,98", 
"24,298", "24,595", "24,727", "24,958", "25,189", "25,42", "26,113", 
"26,179", "26,641", "26,74", "26,872", "26,971", "27,616", "27,832", 
"28,336", "29,668", "29,956", "3", "3,01", "3,011", "3,02", "3,022", 
"3,03", "3,033", "3,04", "3,044", "3,05", "3,055", "3,06", "3,07", 
"3,077", "3,08", "3,088", "3,09", "3,099", "3,1", "3,11", "3,13", 
"3,14", "3,143", "3,15", "3,154", "3,16", "3,165", "3,17", "3,176", 
"3,18", "3,19", "3,198", "3,2", "3,209", "3,212", "3,224", "3,242", 
"3,248", "3,253", "3,26", "3,264", "3,272", "3,275", "3,284", 
"3,286", "3,296", "3,297", "3,308", "3,319", "3,32", "3,33", 
"3,332", "3,341", "3,344", "3,352", "3,363", "3,368", "3,38", 
"3,392", "3,396", "3,404", "3,407", "3,416", "3,428", "3,429", 
"3,44", "3,451", "3,452", "3,462", "3,473", "3,488", "3,5", "3,506", 
"3,512", "3,517", "3,524", "3,536", "3,539", "3,548", "3,56", 
"3,561", "3,572", "3,583", "3,594", "3,596", "3,605", "3,608", 
"3,616", "3,62", "3,632", "3,638", "3,649", "3,656", "3,668", 
"3,68", "3,682", "3,692", "3,693", "3,704", "3,715", "3,716", 
"3,728", "3,74", "3,752", "3,759", "3,764", "3,776", "3,788", 
"3,792", "3,8", "3,812", "3,814", "3,824", "3,825", "3,836", 
"3,847", "3,86", "3,872", "3,884", "3,891", "3,896", "3,908", 
"3,932", "3,956", "3,968", "3,98", "3,99", "3,992", "30,028", 
"30,532", "30,676", "30,892", "31,533", "31,798", "31,943", "32,189", 
"32,763", "32,927", "33,009", "33,173", "33,296", "33,46", "33,583", 
"33,73", "33,788", "34,948", "35,241", "35,57", "36,181", "36,369", 
"37,027", "37,121", "37,5", "38,202", "38,343", "38,437", "38,484", 
"38,531", "39,001", "39,236", "39,659", "39,753", "4,001", "4,004", 
"4,028", "4,04", "4,045", "4,056", "4,064", "4,076", "4,088", 
"4,089", "4,1", "4,112", "4,121", "4,124", "4,136", "4,139", 
"4,16", "4,172", "4,178", "4,191", "4,204", "4,22", "4,232", 
"4,243", "4,256", "4,268", "4,28", "4,282", "4,304", "4,308", 
"4,316", "4,321", "4,328", "4,34", "4,352", "4,364", "4,388", 
"4,4", "4,425", "4,428", "4,442", "4,456", "4,484", "4,498", 
"4,526", "4,529", "4,54", "4,554", "4,582", "4,594", "4,596", 
"4,607", "4,624", "4,638", "4,652", "4,666", "4,685", "4,694", 
"4,708", "4,722", "4,736", "4,75", "4,764", "4,778", "4,792", 
"4,806", "4,82", "4,834", "4,841", "4,848", "4,876", "4,904", 
"4,918", "4,932", "4,945", "4,958", "4,96", "4,974", "4,984", 
"40,06", "40,164", "40,216", "40,528", "40,944", "41,048", "41,152", 
"41,412", "41,568", "41,88", "41,932", "42,4", "42,816", "45,29", 
"45,812", "46,16", "46,682", "47,088", "47,668", "47,842", "48,132", 
"49,872", "49,93", "5,016", "5,023", "5,03", "5,044", "5,058", 
"5,072", "5,075", "5,1", "5,114", "5,128", "5,142", "5,153", 
"5,184", "5,212", "5,218", "5,226", "5,24", "5,244", "5,254", 
"5,268", "5,282", "5,296", "5,324", "5,338", "5,352", "5,366", 
"5,374", "5,38", "5,394", "5,422", "5,436", "5,45", "5,475", 
"5,478", "5,492", "5,506", "5,52", "5,534", "5,562", "5,576", 
"5,59", "5,604", "5,618", "5,632", "5,646", "5,674", "5,685", 
"5,716", "5,73", "5,744", "5,8", "5,832", "5,848", "5,864", "5,88", 
"5,91", "5,912", "5,925", "5,928", "5,944", "5,96", "5,976", 
"50,8", "52,226", "52,474", "53,032", "53,962", "54,024", "54,458", 
"54,582", "55,078", "55,45", "55,636", "56,194", "57,068", "58,564", 
"59,176", "6,008", "6,024", "6,04", "6,045", "6,056", "6,072", 
"6,088", "6,104", "6,12", "6,136", "6,152", "6,232", "6,248", 
"6,264", "6,285", "6,296", "6,312", "6,328", "6,33", "6,345", 
"6,36", "6,375", "6,376", "6,408", "6,44", "6,45", "6,456", "6,472", 
"6,48", "6,488", "6,495", "6,504", "6,51", "6,52", "6,54", "6,552", 
"6,555", "6,584", "6,6", "6,632", "6,645", "6,648", "6,66", "6,664", 
"6,68", "6,705", "6,735", "6,744", "6,76", "6,776", "6,808", 
"6,824", "6,856", "6,872", "6,888", "6,904", "6,92", "6,936", 
"6,952", "6,968", "6,984", "60,808", "62,372", "63,664", "64,448", 
"65,024", "66,968", "68,336", "68,696", "69,632", "7,016", "7,08", 
"7,096", "7,112", "7,128", "7,144", "7,176", "7,192", "7,208", 
"7,24", "7,288", "7,304", "7,32", "7,336", "7,352", "7,368", 
"7,384", "7,4", "7,419", "7,438", "7,476", "7,533", "7,552", 
"7,571", "7,59", "7,609", "7,628", "7,647", "7,666", "7,685", 
"7,704", "7,723", "7,742", "7,78", "7,818", "7,837", "7,856", 
"7,913", "7,932", "7,97", "7,989", "70,712", "71,539", "74,388", 
"74,542", "76,929", "78,623", "8,008", "8,027", "8,084", "8,103", 
"8,122", "8,198", "8,217", "8,236", "8,2588", "8,274", "8,293", 
"8,331", "8,388", "8,407", "8,426", "8,464", "8,502", "8,54", 
"8,635", "8,673", "8,692", "8,711", "8,768", "8,787", "8,806", 
"8,882", "8,901", "8,92", "8,939", "8,958", "8,996", "80,212", 
"83,74", "86,092", "88,664", "9,034", "9,072", "9,11", "9,129", 
"9,205", "9,321", "9,405", "9,447", "9,489", "9,51", "9,552", 
"9,741", "9,783", "9,867", "9,888", "9,93", "9,951", "90,32", 
"91,608", "92,528", "94,552"), class = "factor"), Skawica.Dolna..Skawica. = structure(c(44L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 44L, 58L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 189L, 
174L, 174L, 166L, 71L, 71L, 161L, 166L, 166L, 166L, 182L, 258L, 
258L), .Label = c("", "1,023", "1,045", "1,056", "1,067", "1,078", 
"1,089", "1,1", "1,118", "1,136", "1,154", "1,172", "1,19", "1,208", 
"1,226", "1,244", "1,262", "1,298", "1,316", "1,334", "1,352", 
"1,37", "1,388", "1,406", "1,424", "1,43", "1,442", "1,46", "1,478", 
"1,496", "1,514", "1,518", "1,532", "1,55", "1,56", "1,568", 
"1,586", "1,604", "1,606", "1,622", "1,64", "1,658", "1,676", 
"1,686", "1,694", "1,712", "1,73", "1,7359", "1,748", "1,7644", 
"1,766", "1,7732", "1,782", "1,784", "1,7908", "1,7996", "1,802", 
"1,812", "1,8172", "1,82", "1,826", "1,838", "1,8436", "1,856", 
"1,8612", "1,87", "1,874", "1,892", "1,91", "1,928", "1,938", 
"1,946", "1,964", "1,982", "10", "10,014", "10,068", "10,08", 
"10,245", "10,32", "10,41", "10,44", "10,64", "10,641", "10,74", 
"10,812", "10,96", "101,5", "107", "11,07", "11,184", "11,268", 
"11,28", "11,4", "11,556", "11,6", "11,76", "11,92", "11,928", 
"110,3", "112,5", "116,9", "118", "12,12", "12,192", "12,228", 
"12,24", "12,3", "12,48", "12,56", "12,74", "12,84", "12,88", 
"122,8", "124", "13,2", "13,54", "13,56", "13,62", "13,88", "13,92", 
"130", "14,06", "14,22", "14,28", "14,5", "14,56", "14,64", "14,9", 
"14,94", "15", "15,24", "15,39", "15,58", "15,78", "15,82", "15,92", 
"16,17", "16,26", "16,56", "16,7", "16,95", "16,96", "17,34", 
"17,418", "17,68", "17,73", "18,12", "18,51", "18,66", "18,76", 
"18,9", "19,15", "19,32", "19,48", "19,74", "2", "2,029", "2,036", 
"2,058", "2,064", "2,087", "2,116", "2,145", "2,174", "2,19", 
"2,202", "2,203", "2,232", "2,261", "2,29", "2,348", "2,368", 
"2,376", "2,377", "2,406", "2,435", "2,464", "2,522", "2,534", 
"2,551", "2,562", "2,58", "2,609", "2,638", "2,696", "2,7", "2,725", 
"2,748", "2,783", "2,812", "2,87", "2,899", "2,928", "2,934", 
"2,957", "2,98", "2,986", "20,13", "20,16", "20,58", "21", "21,11", 
"21,42", "21,6", "21,84", "22,13", "22,26", "22,6", "22,66", 
"22,68", "23,1", "23,19", "23,56", "24,02", "24,2", "24,25", 
"24,48", "24,78", "24,94", "25,31", "25,354", "25,4", "25,84", 
"25,86", "25,96", "26,32", "26,78", "26,9", "27,24", "27,7", 
"28,67", "28,72", "28,9556", "29,09", "29,23", "29,58", "29,74", 
"29,85", "3,015", "3,044", "3,12", "3,131", "3,16", "3,189", 
"3,218", "3,26", "3,276", "3,334", "3,363", "3,392", "3,421", 
"3,45", "3,479", "3,508", "3,54", "3,595", "3,61", "3,624", "3,653", 
"3,74", "3,798", "3,82", "3,827", "3,856", "3,914", "3,972", 
"30,25", "30,76", "31,27", "31,78", "32,03", "32,29", "32,8", 
"33,01", "33,304", "33,36", "33,5", "33,92", "34,03", "34,48", 
"35,09", "35,6", "36", "36,68", "36,72", "37,28", "37,84", "38,4", 
"38,82", "39", "39,2", "39,6", "4,001", "4,03", "4,059", "4,1", 
"4,117", "4,146", "4,233", "4,291", "4,32", "4,345", "4,378", 
"4,39", "4,407", "4,494", "4,552", "4,59", "4,61", "4,639", "4,68", 
"4,697", "4,755", "4,813", "4,835", "4,871", "4,9", "4,97", "4,996", 
"40,2", "40,8", "41,4", "42", "42,5", "42,6", "43,2", "44,4", 
"45,04", "45,8", "45,808", "46,32", "46,96", "47,6", "48,24", 
"48,304", "48,88", "49,2", "49,52", "5,028", "5,06", "5,08", 
"5,124", "5,22", "5,26", "5,325", "5,348", "5,38", "5,444", "5,476", 
"5,54", "5,55", "5,57", "5,636", "5,796", "5,828", "5,84", "5,86", 
"5,871", "5,956", "50,16", "50,8", "52,6", "52,78", "53,308", 
"56,05", "56,278", "56,872", "57,4", "57,604", "58,896", "59,44", 
"59,5", "59,848", "59,984", "6,084", "6,13", "6,148", "6,172", 
"6,18", "6,308", "6,404", "6,42", "6,473", "6,5", "6,628", "6,66", 
"6,71", "6,774", "6,82", "6,884", "6,948", "6,98", "60,8", "61,344", 
"62,16", "62,976", "63,15", "63,52", "66,8", "67,12", "67,193", 
"67,558", "67,85", "68,58", "68,726", "69,456", "7", "7,075", 
"7,14", "7,204", "7,236", "7,3", "7,364", "7,376", "7,46", "7,492", 
"7,6", "7,677", "7,716", "7,78", "7,844", "7,9", "7,978", "70,04", 
"70,77", "71,208", "71,354", "71,4", "71,5", "72,54", "75,42", 
"76", "76,14", "76,3", "77,26", "79,5", "8,1", "8,166", "8,2", 
"8,232", "8,279", "8,364", "8,43", "8,5", "8,58", "8,628", "8,727", 
"8,76", "8,793", "8,8", "8,952", "80,35", "81", "82,05", "83,75", 
"86", "86,3", "88,9", "89,8", "9,09", "9,1", "9,189", "9,324", 
"9,4", "9,42", "9,486", "9,585", "9,696", "9,7", "9,75", "9,849", 
"90,25", "91", "96"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Data", 
"Osielec", "Jordanów", "Skawica.Dolna..Skawica."), row.names = 26:50, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your variable into numeric and you're more or less done. I use `scale_y_continuous` here.

```
library(ggplot2)

dane_dlugie$Osielec <- as.numeric(dane_dlugie$Osielec)
ggplot(dane_dlugie, aes(x=Data, y=Osielec, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+labs(x="Data", y="Flow") +
  ggtitle("Osielec")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:5) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d-%m")
```